# Is there a technical term for replacing an element in a vector with the last element of said vector?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

I find myself doing this often enough, but I don't know what to call it. Conceptually, to me at least, I am removing an element from the vector, and as a side effect, for optimization reasons, the last element of the vector takes it's place.

Surely this procedure has a proper name? Please enlighten me so I don't write a `RemoveElementAndReplaceWithLastItem` method.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what use cases find you doing this over and over?

Comment: If I am processing a set of elements where the order doesn't matter. I.e. for objects in a simulation I care about going through each object once per step, removing dead ones. Vectors of data generally give better cache coherency, and the RemoveElementAndReplaceWithLastItem solves the inefficiency problem of erasing in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a generic term for what you're doing. But for your very specific use case I'd suggest naming the function based on your intent rather than on what the operation does. As you said, what the operation does is a side effect, what you're really doing is deleting from the middle.

Therefore, I'd suggest naming the function: **`fast_delete`** (or `quick_remove`, up to you).

Then in a comment in the function implementation you describe the mechanism for doing fast deletion: which is replace the deleted item with the last element. You should even mention what you said above about why you think doing it this way is faster and that the operation does not guarantee that the list will remain in the same order as before.

Comment: As for the two opposite styles of naming given by yourself and James Mohler in another answer, I certainly prefer yours. I can't decide which I like more. `fast_delete` conveys the intent of optimization, while `special_delete` would make it blatantly clear that *something* is going on. Oh well, such details are not so important. The answer to my actual question seems to be "probably not?".

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be called one of the following:

- `ReplaceWithLast()`
- `MoveLastTo()`
- `ConvertQtoPQ()`

As in convert Queue to PriorityQueue

Answer (score 0):

You may name your method/function the following way:

```
replaceInPlace: anElement
```

or for your particular language

```
replaceInPlace(anElement)
```